# disable img tag

Tags: jquery

How to remove href attribute  of an img on a page using jquery?

this img tag does not have any class or ID for referencing

Comment: There has to be something unique about the image, even its just that its the 3rd image in a div named BOB. You will need to provide some type of way of knowing which image it is for others to help you.

Comment: The img tag doesn't have a href property, it generally just has src and alt. Links (the a tag) have a href property but if you remove the href then it's not a link any more. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: can you show us the html please ?

Answer (score 3):

Image tag not have href attribute they have src attribute for image location

using jQuery selector you can remove the src  attribute

Please check on its parent object, if it has either id or class attribute you can use any one of the following.

if the parent (for example consider div) has id.

```
$("div#your-id img").removeAttr('src')
```

if the parent has class.

```
$("div.your-class img").removeAttr('src')
```

Comment: +1. I'd add `$('img[src]').removeAttr('src')` just for the heck of it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the link then I believe you can do something like

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', '#')
```

Answer (score 0):

The image doesn't have a `href` attribute. It has a `src` attribute.

If it's a specific and unique `src` attribute value, then you can just select by it.

E.g. exact match using the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("img[src='foo.gif']").hide();
```

or when src starts with a certain domain, using the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("img[src^='http://example.com']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Image tag not have href attribute they have src attribute for image tag.

Please check on its parent object, if it has either id or class attribute you can use any one of the following.

if the parent (for example consider div) has id.

```
$("div#your-id img").removeAttr('src')
```

if the parent has class.

```
$("div.your-class img").removeAttr('src')
```